# Jumblr API gives bad request while posting image to Tumblr

Tags: android, tumblr, bad-request, jumblr

**What I have**

I have an `image File object` trying to post to `Tumblr` using `Jumblr API`

**My problem**

When I try to post the image I get **com.tumblr.jumblr.exceptions.JumblrException: Bad Request   Response code :400**

**My code**

```
client = new JumblrClient(CONSUMER_KEY,SECRET_KEY);
                            client.setToken(TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET);
                            User user=client.user();
                            userName=user.getName();

                            PhotoPost photoPost=client.newPost(client.user().getBlogs().get(0).getName(),PhotoPost.class);
                            photoPost.setCaption("My Tumblr post");


                            photoPost.setPhoto(new Photo(Methods.FILE_IMAGE));
                            photoPost.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue using Jumblr.

Instead of this method (does it somehow trigger Android gallery? Couldn't find any javadoc for Methods.FILE_IMAGE)

```
photoPost.setPhoto(new Photo(Methods.FILE_IMAGE));
```

I suggest you to try any flavor of

```
photoPost.setData(new File(fileName)); //if it's possible on Android
```

And please try it with different files: Tumblr has not only file-size limitations, but also some weird check for file being valid. ~3% of gif files I upload throw **Bad Request Response code :400**. Those files are not exceeding GIF size limit and they're displayed fine on my machine, but Tumblr, for some reason rejects them, so please try post.setData and try it with some bulletproof-valid file, because from the rest of your code - it definitely looks like you're doing it right

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem posting a video & audio. However, posting an Image worked like a charm..

```
JumblrClient client = new JumblrClient(
                CONSUMER_KEY,
                SECRET_KEY
        );
client.setToken(
                TOKEN,
                TOKEN_SECRET
        );
PhotoPost post = client.newPost(strBlogName, PhotoPost.class);
post.setCaption("This is my caption");
post.setData(new File(fileUri.getPath()));
post.save(); //Initiates upload of image file
```