# Jumblr Implementation android

Tags: android, tumblr, jumblr

**What I have**

I have a photo that needs to posted to `Social API` like `FB,TWITTER,TUMBLR,FLICKR`

**What I wanted**

I wanted to post my photo to `Tumblr`

**What I tried**

I came across `Jumblr Client` which is an official client for `Tumblr`

**My problem**

The document directly says

```
JumblrClient client = new JumblrClient("consumer_key","consumer_secret");
client.setToken("oauth_token", "oauth_token_secret");
```

I have `consumer_key` & `consumer_secret` , how to authenticate and get **oauth_token , oauth_token_secret**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Clinkz. Its pretty forward up there in these links but if still someone is having issue , this is the code which I used in my **Android app** and its working fine. **For Android** at 1st we have to add these two line in app level gradle file: 
**implementation 'com.daksh:loglr:2.1.4' 

implementation 'com.tumblr:jumblr:0.0.13'**

```
private void loginToTumblr() {

       Loglr loglr = Loglr.INSTANCE;
       if(loglr != null) {
           loglr.setConsumerKey("TUBMLR_CONSUMER_KEY"); // Replace with your App's Key
           loglr.setConsumerSecretKey("TUBMLR_CONSUMER_SECRET"); // Replace with your App's Key
           loglr.setUrlCallBack("https://www.callback.com/"); // Replace with your App's Callback
           loglr.setLoginListener(new LoginListener() {
               @Override
               public void onLoginSuccessful(com.tumblr.loglr.LoginResult loginResult) {
               String oAuthToken = loginResult.getOAuthToken();
               String oAuthTokenSecret = loginResult.getOAuthTokenSecret();
               Log.w(TAG, oAuthToken + "\n" + oAuthTokenSecret);                   
               shareOnTumblr(oAuthToken , oAuthTokenSecret);
               }
           });
           loglr.setExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler() {
               @Override
               public void onLoginFailed(RuntimeException e) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "Loglr Exeception: " + e.getMessage());
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! can't login to the tumblr.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           });
         loglr.initiate(this);
       }
       else
           Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong while Loggin in to Tumblr.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
```

After Login if you want to share some Image with some caption, you can use the following code:

```
private void shareOnTumblr(String token, String tokenSecret) {

          IResult iResult = new IResult() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(String result) {
                  loadingBar.hide();
                  Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }

              @Override
              public void onError(String error) {
                  Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          };

          String caption   = "IMAGE CAPTION GOES HERE";
          String imagePath = "IMAGE PATH GOES HERE"; //It must a String

          String params[] = new String[]{token, tokenSecret , caption, imagePath};
          new TumblrPostAsyncTask(iResult).execute(params);
       }
```

```
public static class TumblrPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

            IResult iResult;

            TumblrPostAsyncTask(IResult iResult){
                this.iResult = iResult;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                boolean result;
                try {
                    JumblrClient client = new JumblrClient("TUBMLR_CONSUMER_KEY", "TUBMLR_CONSUMER_SECRET");
                    client.setToken(params[0], params[1]);

                    PhotoPost post = client.newPost(client.user().getBlogs().get(0).getName(),PhotoPost.class);
                    Log.w(TAG, params[2] + " " + params[3]);
                    post.setCaption(params[2]);
                    post.setData(new File(params[3]));
                    post.save();
                    result = true;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Tumblr's Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    result = false;
                }

               return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
                super.onPostExecute(success);
                Log.w(TAG, "On Post Execute: " + success);
                if(success)
                    iResult.onSuccess("Successfully Posted on Tumblr.");
                else
                    iResult.onError("Sorry! couldn't Post on Tumblr.");

            }
        }
```

Interface looks like this:

```
public interface IResult {

    void onSuccess(String result);
    void onError(String error);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I must admit, the Jumblr documentation is lacking.
Refer the following links. They will answer your question.
1) Complete Login Procedure code : [Github Project](https://github.com/dakshsrivastava/TumblrJumblrImplementation)
2) Code snippet to post Images to Tumblr : [Code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436097/jumblr-api-gives-bad-request-while-posting-image-to-tumblr/34588227#34588227)

Comment: Glad I could help.